# Textbox contents are overwritten, not appended to, on paste

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I've got a VB.Net application I inherited that has an annoying issue with the textboxes.

They don't seem to behave in a 'standard' manner. For example, pressing 'Ctrl+A' with the cursor in them doesn't select all. Mouse wheel won't scroll the box.

But the main issue that I want to get fixed is the paste problem. When I have text on the clipboard, and I paste, the contentc of the box are not appended to. Instead they are overwritten.

It's not a case of accidentally having all of the contents selected when I paste. Even when I'm very careful to have nothing selected, the contents are overwritten.

This happens with all textboxes in this application. So far I've browsed through the properties of one of the TextBoxes to see if anything looked related - nothing did. I searched the code to see if a property was set somewhere to account for this - nothing was. And I Googled and checked here but couldn't find a simmilar issue.

I don't work in VB often so I might be missing something obvious - but I can't find the answer anywhere.

And just to see what would happen I just added a new TextBox. It had the same behavior despite my putting it in and not modifying any of it's properties or writing any code related to it.

Being able to append text to what is present in these textboxes would be really helpful for the people who use this program.

Thanks for taking the time to read my question, and for any help you can provide!

I don't know what aditional info might be helpful, so if you need anything let me know.

Comment: Posting at least one line of code would be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure the standard TextBox is being used and not a custom **derived** one?  It would appear at the very top of the ToolBox, separate from the rest of the normal controls, if it was custom.  If that's not the case, is WndProc() being overridden anywhere?  How about IMessageFilter()?

Comment: Douglas - Obviously if I had any idea where this was originating I would have posted some relevant code. But I hade no idea (thus my question here) so what do you want from me - all 37,806 lines in the project maybe?

Comment: Idle_Mind - According to the properties of one of the TextBoxes it's a System.Windows.Forms.TextBox. I don't see anything that looks like it's a custom conrtol in the ToolBox. And a search doesn't turn up any instance of IMessageFilter or WndProc

Answer (score 1):

```
texbox1.text = "Myoldvalue" 

textbox1.text & = " Add this too" 

msgbox(textbox1.text) 


OutPut : 

Myoldvalue Add this too
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the TextBox supports the standard clipboard keys in the standard way (insert at cursor, replace selection) but not Ctrl-A.

The RichTextBox does support Ctrl-A so that might be a quick fix.

Otherwise use Textbox.KeyDown event to handled Ctrl-A

```
    If e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        TextBox1.SelectAll()
        e.Handled = True
    End If
```